# Trying to setup sanity.io

Tags: npm, backend, node-modules, sanity, headless-cms

Every time I use this command 'npm run dev' to open sanity studio, I get this error :

```
✔ Checking configuration files...
Sanity Studio using vite@4.3.9 ready in 1382ms and running at http://localhost:3333/
node:events:491

  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: Expected pattern to be a non-empty string
    at picomatch (F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\picomatch\lib\picomatch.js:48:11)
    at createPattern (F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\anymatch\index.js:27:18)
    at F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\anymatch\index.js:91:21
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at anymatch (F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\anymatch\index.js:91:6)
    at F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:272:51
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
    at F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:270:22
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at WatchHelper.filterDir (F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:269:43)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:647:10)
    at NodeFsHandler._boundHandleError (F:\[PORTFOLIO]\chatclique\chatclique_backend\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:303:43)
    at ReaddirpStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Node.js v18.16.1

[here are all the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcyXT.png)

I've tried to uninstall node.js and redownload it and yet nothing changed.